# Obviously chatty comment … flag declined?

Tags: support, comments, flags, declined-flags

Chatty comments don't get more clear-cut than [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120350/determine-if-an-array-contains-something-other-than-2/120364#comment295393_120364):

> @WheatWizard thanks!

And yet, somehow…

[image: no longer needed – Stephen Leppik yesterday declined]

Excuse me for a moment, but… what? The other 14 flags I raised on comments saying "thanks a lot" and nothing else were helpful, but this one is declined?

Comment: I don't know why it is inconsistent, but comments thanking people golfing their solution are usually fine.

Comment: Comments like this are only an issue if there are a lot of them. There's no harm in removing them, but there isn't really much of a reason to, eitherl

Comment: Could it be that in the other 14 answers the poster included a "Thank you" in the answer body? Usually the way I do it: If the comment helped me golfing my answer I introduce a notice along the lines "Thanks @SomeUser for -42 bytes!" and flag their comment for removal since it's no longer needed. In my eyes this keeps the answer self-contained and tidy but I wouldn't start flagging comments on other answers (of course there are exceptions) since it's not my decision how different people want to pay their respect.

Comment: For me is ok to say "thank you" "good morning" "have a nice day" ...

Comment: Possibly I not understand this discussion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the flags were cast on *thank you* replies to suggested improvements, which had been incorporated and acknowledged in their respective answers. Neither the *thank you* comments nor the original suggestions served any purpose anymore, so I deleted them.

However, the answer of one of the comments did not mention it at all. While I'm not sure the *thank you* comment is still *needed*, deleting a reply to a post without deleting the post itself felt awkward, so I decided to preserve both comments.

Answer (score 4):

One chatty comment isn't really an issue, especially if it's a "thank you" comment. It's not really worth the mods' time to remove singular chatty comments on posts. Chatty comments only really need to be flagged when there are multiple, excessively chatty comments, and then it's usually more effective to raise a custom mod flag on the post itself.

Of course, spam/rude/abusive comments are a whole different story - flag those with great prejudice whenever you see them.